# ASP.net MVC Directory Browsing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-development-serv, directory-browsing

Im adding the ability to upload images to my ASP.net mvc application. Basically the user selects an image and I upload it to an Images folder which i've created in my solution folder structure. This works great and the image uploads to the images folder.

The problem I have is now displaying the image back to the browser. My question is how do I change directory browsing properties of the Asp.net Development Server (localHost:blah blah) so that the images directory i.e. http://localHost:9823/Images/UploadedImageName.jpg shows up in the browser?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple options that I've used. Pros and cons to each style!

**In The View**

You could have your Views configured to use this style:

```
 <img src="<%=ResolveUrl("~/Images/foo.png")" %> />
```

This could be refactored a handful of ways. An extension method perhaps, or codebehind your View.

**Controller Method + Route**

Create a new Controller to serve up images. Ensure you have a route with a default.

```
 public class Images
 {
   public FileResult GetImage(string fileName) //foo.png
    {
        string fullPath = "~/Images/" +  fileName;
        return base.File(fullPath, "image/jpeg");
    }
 }

...
routes.MapRoute("UserImage",
                "Image/{filename}",
                new { controller = "Images", action = "GetImage", 
                      fileName=filename });
```

Comment: You must validate the filename to prevent path traversal.  (eg, `fileName=..\web.config`)